# Identify symlinked python files for import in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, symlink, pylance

I am working with a complex body of code where some python files get symlinked to a directory, from which I would like to import them. For example:

```
accessible_module
| __init__.py
| sourceA.py
```

The files `__init__.py` and `sourceA.py` are symlinked to source files that live elsewhere. I have another file with an import statement

```py
from accessible_module import sourceA
```

My code works at runtime, but I would like VS Code to be able to resolve the import for linting and autocompletion. At present, I get an import error from pylance. I have verified that the `accessible_module` is present in the PYTHONPATH, and I have checked that the import statements work if I replace the `__init__.py` and `sourceA.py` symlinks with their actual source files (however, this is not a viable long-term solution for me).

Is there a way to get VS Code to correctly recognize these symlinked imports?

Comment: weird... I would have thought that this would be fixed by https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1031#issuecomment-801524605. what version of the Pylance extension for VS Code do you have installed? Is it 2021.3.2 or greater? If you end up raising a new issue ticket, or commenting on the existing one, please let me know with a link so I can follow along.

Comment: Indeed I also thought this was strange. I am running v2023.09.30 of Pylance for VS Code. If you think it could be a bug, I guess I should open an issue ticket. I just commented on the thread you linked

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following fields to your `settings.json`:

```json
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "path/to/your/source" //for example, "./src/accessible_module"
]
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it did not help, unfortunately